# Разложение wav файла на массив байтов и выполнение БПФ

Tags: c#, wav

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, я с помощью этого кода получил массив байтов и записал его в файл.

```
`using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(inFile))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Length];
                file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("ConvertedFile\\bytes.txt", false);

                foreach (byte b in buffer)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(b);
                }

                sw.Close();
            }`
```

Теперь его и нужно отправлять на вход быстрого преобразования Фурье?

Подскажите, пожалуйста ещё, я загружаю wav файл в метод длительностью 10 секунд и у меня выбрасывается исключение[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне нужно сделать?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2011/10/31/more-fun-with-the-fast-fourier-transform/) есть метод `ReadWav(string fileName)`

Comment: Мой косяк. Небольшая ошибка в коде. Поменяйте 44 на 0 в строчке WaveFile.Read(wave,0,Convert.ToInt32(WaveFile.Length));

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Comment: @Andrey273 еще кое-что подправил в коде, утром не успел проверить просто.

Comment: Угу, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Приветствую!

Согласно [структуре WAV](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/), первые 44 байта WAV файла служат для хранения служебной информации. Соответственно, вам нужно считать в `byte[]` только полезные амплитуды, хранящиеся в секции `data`.

Обычно на вход БПФ подаются вещественные значения амплитуд, поэтому вы должны сконвертировать секцию `data`, которую вы считали в `byte[]` в массив `double[]`, исходя из того, что каждая амплитуда кодируется 4-мя байтами.

Для БПФ можете воспользоваться бесплатным математическим пакетом [Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms/Fourier.htm), предварительно переписав ваши `double[]` в массив комплексных чисел `Complex[]`, оставляя мнимую часть пустой.

Вот код чтения полезной секции из WAV:

```
public static Double[] prepare(String wavePath)

    {
        Double[] data;
        byte[] wave;
        System.IO.FileStream WaveFile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(wavePath);
        wave = new byte[WaveFile.Length];
        data = new Double[(wave.Length - 44) / 4];//shifting the headers out of the PCM data;
        WaveFile.Read(wave,0,Convert.ToInt32(WaveFile.Length));//read the wave file into the wave variable
        /***********Converting and PCM accounting***************/
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (BitConverter.ToInt32(wave, 44+i*4)) / 4 294 967 296.0;

        }

        return data;
    }
```