# Визуализация wav-файла в виде волны во временной области

Tags: c#, аудио, график, wav

Как представить wav-файл в виде зависимости амплитуды от времени, чтобы получилось как на этом рисунке, который я получил с помощью матлаб. И результат чтобы можно было отобразить в pictureBox
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Можно тут глянуть](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/audio-video/soundviewer.aspx), кстати если Вы загуглите этот вопрос, Вы получите достаточно много ответов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала поймите, сколькими байтами кодируется одна амплитуда в  вашем WAV файле. Если 4 байта - пример кода я уже Вам [предлагал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643481/). Возможны разные варианты : 1,2,3,4 и так далее, от этого зависит код по чтению, находящийся по ссылке. 
Далее поймите, какое количество каналов в вашем файле. Если mono - читайте байты амплитуд подряд, если stereo - то через одну (одна для левого канала, другая для правого).
Далее, когда уже имеете массивы `double[]`для обоих каналов (либо один массив в случае mono) - это и есть амплитуды. Отложите их последовательно на графике `Chart`вместо `pictureBox`, будет удобнее.

Comment: понял, спасибо, у меня один канал используется в звуке

Comment: и для кодирования амплитуд используется 16 бит, в этой строчке получается у нас должно остаться 65536 вместо 4 294 967 296.0?  `data[i] = (BitConverter.ToInt32(wave, 44+i*4)) / 4 294 967 296.0`

Comment: @Andrey273 да, 2 байта, следовательно 65536.

Comment: это как раз и получается, что кодируется только одна амплитуда?

Comment: @Andrey273 одна амплитуда = 2 байта. Делим на 65536 для того чтобы нормализовать амплитуду от 0 до 1.  Кстати, можете приводить к Int16 а не к Int32 в этом случае.

Comment: понял, спасибо большое

Comment: это здесь я так понял тоже 44+i*4 нужно не на 4 умножать, а теперь на 2?

Comment: @Andrey273 да, все верно. Сдвиг на 2 байта.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56006/discussion-between-andrey273-and-exodium).