# Как реализовать волны голосовых сообщений для визуализации?

Tags: математика, аудио, flutter, dart, звукозапись

я хочу реализовать волны голосовых сообщений для визуализации. Я не понимаю как это вообще делается. То есть как определить высоту волны.

**Как я сделал:** У меня всего этих делений волн должно быть 35. Я сделал из звука list с байтами, далее сгруппировал их на 35 групп и нашёл у группы среднее число и это среднее число я сделал высотой, но это не работает (то есть неправильная высота даётся).

Comment: Почти дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643814

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В первую очередь, вам нужно из файла со звуком выудить значения амплитуд, то есть, построить ваш *list с байтами* правильно.

Важно понимать, что такие форматы как ogg, mp3, и так далее, которые пересылаются в большинстве мессенджеров - находятся в сильно сжатом виде и должны быть сначала декодированы, чтобы получить значения амплитуд. Именно значения амплитуды определяют высоту столбиков на диаграме.

И еще один вопрос - как, имея массив с амплитудами (который после декодирования "в лоб" может оказаться огромным - 5 минут аудио в режиме стерео на 44 кГц - это примерно 40 мегабайт) усреднить его, чтобы нарисовать картинку.

Здесь нужно применить два метода:

- вычисление RMS - среднеквадратического отклонения - взять несколько значений амплитуды подряд и подставить в формулу из Википедии.
- перевод в логарифмическую шкалу - от полученного значения RMS нужно взять логарифм по основанию 10. Это нужно для того, чтобы учесть психоакустические особенности слуха.

Совсем "умные" шкалы громкости также учитывают множество других фактов из психоакустики и выдают еще более "достоверный" результат, но для вашей задачи он будет излишним.

Также может быть полезным построение статистической гистограммы амплитуд - маловероятно, что голосовое сообщение записано аудиоинженером на профессиональный микрофон (вероятно как раз обратное - пишут на бутерброд с сервелатом, а говорят в противоположную от микрофона сторону).

Гистограмма позволит прогнать что-то вроде нормализации, что позволит исключить неинформативные картинки - горизонтальную линию (писали, отвернув голову от микрофона) и наоборот - забор из пиков (орали прямо в микрофон, держа смарт "по купечески", *торцом к роту*)

Comment: Если кому интересно узнать, зачем нужен логарифм, см. [закон Вебера — Фехнера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0).

Comment: Впервые сталкиваюсь с практикой перевода аудиоданных из аудиофайла в логарифмическую шкалу. Буду знать, если что. До этого думал, что это нужно в основном для рассчёта конструкций регуляторов громкости или программирования программных регуляторов.

Comment: @Опан если вы откроете любой музыкальный софт, увидите переключатель между логарифмической и линейной шкалами. Реальную громкость видно как раз на логарифмике - выше даже на закон сослались.

Answer (score 1):

Если значение амплитуды задаёте подсчетом среднего арифметического целой группы байт, то зачем тогда каждый байт по отдельности, как думаете? Эти группы скорее всего так называемые чанки. (то же, что и группы семплов), а каждый семпл (то же, что и значение амплитуды) может состоять из одного, двух или трёх байт. (это указывают в заголовке аудиофайла любого стандартного формата) Вот на это число и нужно делить скорее всего.

В общем, вопрос нужно конкретизировать (как всегда пишут те, кто закрывают вопросы) Иначе трудновато понять ситуацию.