# Как конвертировать wav stereo в mono?

Tags: c#, аудио, .net-4.0, bass.dll

*Догадываюсь что такие вопросы здесь не любят, но всё же рискну...*

Как сконвертировать аудиофайл в wav есть рабочий [пример](http://www.bass.radio42.com/help/html/7e999084-acae-72fd-fd0a-2a00dcb5ec55.htm), но вот как изменить wav мне примеров найти не удалось даже по англоязычным запросам. Предполагал что [этот пример](http://bass.radio42.com/help/html/50c9884f-89b0-5fc7-dc36-3b5d97543195.htm) нужно разрабатывать, но я так и не понял, как там указать wav файл с которым код должен работать...

Может кто уже имел дело с bass.dll (bass.net) и может подсказать решение?

**upd**

[Нашёл код](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET) который должен реализовывать данную возможность, но почему-то сконвертированный им wav файл не воспроизводится. Кто-то может подсказать, в чём причина?

```
public static void MixStereoToMono()
    {
        byte[] input = File.ReadAllBytes("options.wav");
        byte[] output = new byte[input.Length / 2];
        int outputIndex = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < input.Length; n += 4)
        {
            int leftChannel = BitConverter.ToInt16(input, n);
            int rightChannel = BitConverter.ToInt16(input, n + 2);
            int mixed = (leftChannel + rightChannel) / 2;
            byte[] outSample = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)mixed);

            // copy in the first 16 bit sample
            output[outputIndex++] = outSample[0];
            output[outputIndex++] = outSample[1];
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes("options1.wav", output);
    }
```

Изначальный аудиофайл имеет такие характеристики: PCM, 22.1 kHz, 2 chn, 16 bit, 705.6 kbit/s

**upd 2**

Оказывается проблема выше указанного кода в том, что он не учитывает заголовок файла, с которым нужно работать отдельно. Сейчас попытаюсь найти информацию о корректном формировании заголовка.

Comment: Самое простое, если несжатый WAV, то прочесть заголовок, данные, выкинуть каждый второй байт данных (или пару байт, если 16бит), выкинуть второй канал и подправить дискретизацию и число каналов в заголовке.

Comment: Я новичок, поэтому для меня это совсем не просто...

Comment: Ага. Нашёл пример кода с алгоритмом, о котором вы говорили. Но созданный файл почему-то не воспроизводится. Можете подсказать, в чём причина? http://pasted.co/c038bea3 Изначальный аудиофайл имеет такие характеристики: PCM, 22.1 kHz, 2 chn, 16 bit, 705.6 kbit/s

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643481/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-wav-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%91%d0%9f%d0%a4/643553#643553). Помогал считывать амплитуды из WAV, но там случай для mono. В случае stereo вам нужно читать каждую нечетную либо четную амплитуду.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Проблема приведённого мною выше кода оказывается в том, что он не учитывает заголовок файла. Сейчас буду пытаться сформировать корректный заголовок.